# MYSQL Query: How to get a list from two tables and need many judgement

Tags: mysql, sql

Here're my requirements:

```
**FIELD**              **MEANING** **REMARK** **REQUEST** **RESPONCE**
  userId                user's id                  Y
 users.userId                                                  Y
 users.followCount      the number the                         Y
                        user followed
 users.followStatus     do I follow                            Y
                        the user
 users.workCount        the number the                         Y
                        user's work
```

(`Y` means sending or returning the field, `users` is a list)

Here's my table: `TB_FOLLOW`

```
**FIELDS**             **TYPE**             **REMARK**
 USER_ID1              int(12) NOT NULL     first user' id
 USER_ID2              int(12) NOT NULL     second user's id
 RELATIONSHIP          char(2) NOT NULL     00:both following
                                            02:userid1 follows userid2
                                            o6:userid2 follows userid1
```

Here's my table:`TB_WORK`

```
**FIELD**   **ATTRIBUTE**   **TYPE**                     **REMARK**
  WORK_ID       PK          int(12),AUTO_INCREMENT       work's id
  USER_ID                   int(12),NOT NULL             user'id
```

And here's my try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS WORK_COUNT, TB_USER.USER_ID FROM TB_WORK, TB_USER WHERE TB_WORK.USER_ID = TB_USER.USER_ID AND TB_USER.USER_ID IN
(
SELECT TB_FOLLOW.USER_ID1 AS USER_ID FROM TB_FOLLOW WHERE TB_FOLLOW.USER_ID2=19 AND (TB_FOLLOW.RELATIONSHIP="00" OR TB_FOLLOW.RELATIONSHIP="06")
UNION
SELECT TB_FOLLOW.USER_ID2 AS USER_ID FROM TB_FOLLOW WHERE TB_FOLLOW.USER_ID1=19  AND (TB_FOLLOW.RELATIONSHIP="00" OR TB_FOLLOW.RELATIONSHIP="02")
) GROUP BY TB_WORK.USER_ID
```

But when I do this, if the user has not any work, the record will not return.
And I don't know how to get the other attributes: `followStatus`, `followCount`.
Hope someone would help me, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it's mysql.

Comment: Please post sample data and expected results - I can't quite see what you're trying to do...